# Why is the Button initialized in OnClick, even though it doesn't have access to OnCreate, where it was actually initialized?

Tags: java, android, initialization, declaration

I am trying to understand declaration and initialization better, and don't really understand why you can change the text of the Button in OnClick even though it doesn't have access to OnCreate, since its another function.

When also declaring the variable in onCreate it doesn't work, but only initializing does. Please explain why. Thanks

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btn.setText("Sample Text");
    }
}
```

So I am trying to undestand why you can change the Button´s Text, even though it hasnt been initialized in OnClick. Thanks a lot <3

Answer (score 0):

It has been initialized.  See the variable btn?  Its at the class level, not inside a function.  That means the variable is stored in the instance of the class, not on the stack, and will persist between function calls to the same instance of the class.  Since onClick will be called on the same instance as onCreate, when you initialize it in onCreate it will stay initialized.  So when onClick is called the value is already set.

Comment: So if I define a variable in a Class, and a function initializes it, then the other functions can use it because they are in the same Class. Right?

Comment: Right.  If you define it in a function, then its only usable in that function (and the next time you call the function you get a new version-  the variable isn't kept around).  An interesting corner case is if you define a variable in a function with the same name as a class variable, using that name refers to the version of it defined in the function, and you'd have to use this.name to refer to the class variable version (which gets confusing, so its considered a bad practice to do this).

Answer (score 0):

You have a `Button`  `(Button btn;)` and currently it is null so you can't do anything with it.

Inside `onCreate` your button is initialized  (`btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button);`)  an now you can assign it click 
listener as you did - `btn.setOnClickListener(this);`

`setOnClickListener` is meant to say - when this button is clicked called `onClick` method.

And inside `onClick` you can change the text.

---

*So I am trying to undestand why you can change the Button´s Text, even though it hasnt been initialized in OnClick.*

your `btn` is  <s>**as a global variable**</s> at the class level meaning you can access it from methods that inside your class, `onCreate` is the first thing that will get called (this is why you the button initialization oh there)
and after that you have initialized button, and you can change your button text.

Comment: Nitpick-  it isn't a global variable, Java doesn't have those.  Its an instance variable on the MainActivity class.  If you later create another MainActivity, it will not be initialized until onCreate is called again, and it will have a different value that the first instance.

Comment: @Gabe Well, I can only agree with you, thank you for pointing this out - I didn't want to give away any misleading information.